# Regexp to check if two charachters are in the same quantity in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

**For instance I want to match string only if it has characters "1" and "2" in the same quantity in it.**

Input 1: **1932213** (match, since there are same quantity of "1" and "2")
Input 2: **11932213** (don't match, since there are more "1" than "2")

How do I get such a regexp ?
illustration of this could be:
**( ?=(.*1){n} ) ( ?=(.*2){n} )**

The question is
how to put `n` in regex ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a regex alone, but it's trivial to accomplish programatically:

```js
const getOccurrences = (str, num) => [...str].reduce((a, b) => a + (b === num), 0);
const validate = str => getOccurrences(str, '1') === getOccurrences(str, '2');

console.log(
  validate('1932213'),
  validate('11932213'),
  validate('1'),
  validate('12'),
);
```

Another approach:

```js
const getOccurrences = (str, num) => (str.match(new RegExp(num, 'g')) || []).length;
const validate = str => getOccurrences(str, '1') === getOccurrences(str, '2');

console.log(
  validate('1932213'),
  validate('11932213'),
  validate('1'),
  validate('12'),
);
```

Comment: The whole point is to have this logic in regexp pattern, something like this
**( ?=(.*1){n} ) ( ?=(.*2){n} )**

Comment: The logic you want is not possible to put into a regular expression, unfortunately.